# One word for "tend to ignore"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am reading an economist article. For some reason the writing seems extremely simple and colloquial.

For an exercise, I want to re-write it by retaining the arguments, refutation, facts but by changing the wordings.

What could be a word for "tend to ignore"? (ignore something good, or bad)

Original text:

> the migrants tended to ignore its potential for making a new home

Like discard? reject? inconsiderate? (these do not feel right though)

Comment: At the least, indicate your research. Second, the single word request tag is "for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally the word I would chose for that context is:

> [Neglect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neglect)
>
> *to give little attention or respect to :  disregard The building has been neglected for years.*

But you might also consider:

> [Snub](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snub)
>
> *to treat with contempt or neglect snub an old acquaintance*

and,

> [Remiss](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remissness)
>
> *showing neglect or inattention*

or, if you need to make it lighter:

> [Abstracted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstracted)
>
> *withdrawn in mind :  inattentive to one's surroundings said hello but seemed abstracted*